# Replace 2 of 3 hyphens in a filename with SPACE hyphen SPACE in Powershell

Tags: rename, filenames, replacement

I have been attempting to modify the following example given for a similar question in Powershell, to match my own needs.  Running the example works fine.

Please could you assist in how to change the code for my needs below?

Example given:

```
~$test = '1942.009.405_SIENESE 16TH CENTURY__1988_09_08_DATA REPORT_TX_4305010_0002.pdf'~

~$test -replace '^(.+\d{4})`_(\d{2})`_(\d{2}.+)$', '$1-$2-$3'~
```

Result:

```
1942.009.405_SIENESE 16TH CENTURY__1988-09-08_DATA REPORT_TX_4305010_0002.pdf
```

I want to modify this code so that filenames like:

`DDG376-Run1-432.21-543.32 (1)`

to become:

`DDG376 - Run 1 - 432.21-534.32 (1)`

I would imagine if I could replace `(.+\d{4})` with a search for ANY character string up to 6 characters, a hyphen, 4 characters, hyphen, (remainder) and then replace the hyphens with SPACE hyphen SPACE it would work.  I don't know how to make the digit search an 'any character string' search.

Any assistance would be amazing.

Comment: Have you tried a tool like [this one](https://regexr.com/3c0lf) to help you learn powershell regular expression syntax?  I myself find them useful.